# Python os.path.join - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror, export-to-csv, nonetype

I'm relative new to python and I am trying to run an open-sourced project from my windows command prompt. However, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\Joycelin>cd C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\algofx\script
s

C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\algofx\scripts>python randomwalk.p
y GBPUSD
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomwalk.py", line 62, in <module>
    pair, d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\Users\Joycelin\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This is part of the script (`randomwalk.py`) where the error occurs:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        pair = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print("You need to enter a currency pair, e.g. GBPUSD, as a command line parameter.")
    else:
        np.random.seed(42)  # Fix the randomness

        S0 = 1.5000
        spread = 0.002
        mu_dt = 1400  # Milliseconds
        sigma_dt = 100  # Millseconds
        ask = copy.deepcopy(S0) + spread / 2.0
        bid = copy.deepcopy(S0) - spread / 2.0
        days = month_weekdays(2016, 2)  # January 2014
        current_time = datetime.datetime(
            days[0].year, days[0].month, days[0].day, 0, 0, 0,
        )

 # Loop over every day in the month and create a CSV file
        # for each day, e.g. "GBPUSD_20150101.csv"
        for d in days:
            print(d.day)
            current_time = current_time.replace(day=d.day)
            outfile = open(
                os.path.join(
                    settings.CSV_DATA_DIR, 
                    "%s_%s.csv" % (
                        pair, d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
                    )
                ), 
            "w")
            outfile.write("Time,Ask,Bid,AskVolume,BidVolume\n")
```

I tried to identify where is the 'None' value that raise the error but still can't figure out if it's from the `settings.CSV_DATA_DIR` or `d.strftime("%Y%m%d")`(or could it be something else?).

This is part of script `settings.py`

```
CSV_DATA_DIR = os.environ.get("//Users/Joycelin/csv_data")
OUTPUT_RESULTS_DIR = os.environ.get("//Users/Joycelin/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/algofx/output_results")
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you don't have environment variables with those names - are you sure you want that `os.environ.get` call in there?

Comment: Where did `settings.py` come from? Was it in the example or did you write it? `os.environ.get` gets environment variables but that's a path... `CSV_DATA_DIR = "//Users/Joycelin/csv_data"` and etc.. should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Yous settings.py should contain something like this:

```
CSV_DATA_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\Joycelin\\csv_data'
OUTPUT_RESULTS_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\Joycelin\\output_results'
```

I don't think you want to put your output in one of the directories in your Anaconda installation.